# Can't serve api on web browser

Tags: go

Below is the code for making a api server with go gin. But it has some troubles that when I call with postman a GET api work. But when I call by pasting the url to google chrome browser it failed

```golang
router := gin.Default()

config := cors.DefaultConfig()
config.AllowAllOrigins = true

router.Use(cors.New(config))

router.Run("4000")
```

Comment: `4000` is not a valid address, use `router.Run(":4000")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `router.Run(":4000")`

*Note*: If you don't mention any address and just `colon` (`:`) followed by `port`, it will listen on TCP port 4000 on all available unicast and anycast IP addresses of the local system.